Getting http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease message
I am getting the message "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
" message after I run sudo apt-get update. How do I resolve this issue?  thank you!

Please post the full output of sudo apt update
